# Using AMQP to collect events

Tags: architecture, scalability, amqp

Does AMQP has any advantages over an ad-hoc implementation for a simple stats gathering scenario? It works like this - clients send events (more than we care to put into persistent storage) to (several) web workers, the workers aggrregate them and write to a single database. I don't think I should consider using AMQP for this because I'll still need web workers to receive events from clients through HTTP and to publish them. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use AMQP for this but it is better to use stats gathering software. For instance, if you set up Graphite for your data collection/graphing service, and you add a `statsd` frontend, then you can send data points via UDP (which is lowest overhead) and let statsd aggregate and write to the Graphite db. The key thing is that `statsd` supports statistical collection. You configure your statsd server to collect 1 in 10 data points, then the statsd client randomly sends one of every 10 datapoints to the server (limiting network traffic) and `statsd` calculates aggregates grossed up 10 times. For instance, if you get 3 datapoints in your aggregation time period, and their values are 38, 42 and 40, statsd would record one average datapoint of 40, and an event volume of 30 events.

If you decide to go this route, be sure to consider using metricsd which is statsd compatible but supports more measurement types https://github.com/mojodna/metricsd